# Prevent multiple Cython processes from simultaneously compiling the same code

Tags: python, parallel-processing, cython

I have a Cython .pyx file (CyFoo.pyx) that I import using pyximport (in PyFoo.py). If I run PyFoo.py, everything is fine. But if I delete my Cython cache in ~/.pyxbld and try to simultaneously start 5 versions of PyFoo.py (it's a parallel process), then it seems like pyximport tries to compile the code repeatedly and overwrites half-written build files in ~/.pyxbld, leading to corrupted files and causing the compile to fail.

Is there any way to deal with the fact that Cython doesn't have any kind of locking to prevent this from happening? Is there a better workaround than writing a setup.py file and manually building the Cython files that way?

Comment: I keep [a standard `setup.py` file](https://gist.github.com/saullocastro/7683277) and just edit for each project, it is a much more robust approach than the `pyximport.install()` option, specially for more complex projects where you need to pass extra options to the compiler, for example `/openmp` for parallel processing...

Comment: @SaulloCastro could you provide an article or blogpost with good explanation for usage setup.py? I'm new for cython, and its hard to find good tutorials and how-to's..

Comment: @akaRem sorry for the very late reply, [here is a Gist of my setup.py](https://gist.github.com/saullocastro/7683277)